# Why is including phase info in chemical reactions important?

Tags: phase

I would like to ask why do we have to include the phase change in a chemical reaction e.g from  solid to aqueous or liquid. Why is it important actually?

Comment: You don't have to include it, but it is often useful - for example this: $$\ce{Ag+ (aq) + Cl- (aq) -> AgCl (s)}$$

Comment: It gives a complete chemical and physics picture. Would you think that dropping mention of one of the reactants help understand all the chemistry that is going on in a given reaction? Because different phases have different Gibbs free energies, and that information is important to understanding what is going on, the phases should, in general, always be mentioned.